# Are $L^p$ topologies compatible?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Consider the subspace topologies on $L^p\cap L^q$ be induced by $L^p$ and $L^q$ respectively. Then, are these subspace topologies compatible?

Moreover, I'm curious about the special case $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does "compatible" mean in this question? At least the following is true: $\|\cdot\|_p+\|\cdot\|_q$ is a complete norm on $L^p\cap L^q$ (essentially because if $f_n\to g$ in $L^p$ and $f_n\to h$ in $L^q$ then $g=h$ a.e.), which norm defines a topology that is finer than that from $L^p$ (resp. $L^q$).

Comment: Also, the following is true: the intersection of the $L^p$ and $L^q$ topologies on $L^p\cap L^q$ is *separated*. Indeed, if $\lambda$ is a linear form on $L^p\cap L^q$ that is continuous for both the $L^p$ and $L^q$ topologies and has $\lambda(f)=2$ say, then $\lambda^{-1}((-1,1))$ and $\lambda^{-1}((1,3))$ are open for both the $L^p$ and $L^q$ topologies, are disjoint, and contain $0$ and $f$ respectively. And $f$ is easy to find using the description of the duals of $L^p$ and $L^q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f\in L^1\cap L^2$ and $f_t(x)=t^n\,f(t\,x)$. Then $f_t\in L^1\cap L^2$ and
$$
\|f_t\|_1=\|f\|_1,\quad \|f_t\|_2=t^{n/2}\,\|f\|_2.
$$
As $t\to0$, $f_t$ converges to $0$ in $L^2$, but not in $L^1$. The example can be changed to cover the case $L^p\cap L^q$.

Comment: Yes, but what question exactly are you responding to? Rubertos (OP) wrote "compatible", and it seems like you're answering the question of whether the two topologies are equal. Which is a fine question to answer, and perhaps indeed what OP meant, but maybe you should have clarified this.

Comment: For lack of a better definition of "compatible topologies", and since the OP has not clarified its meaning, I think that it is a sensible answer.

Comment: I used my own definition of compatible: there are sequences that converge in one topology and do not converge in the other, so I say they are not compatible. If that is not what the OP meant, I will happily delete my answer.

Comment: It's a perfectly sensible definition, I'm just suggesting you should state it at the start of your answer (whether or not it's what OP actually meant, other people might read this and find it interesting, better let them know exactly what is being proved).